# Problem with pendrive

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I have problem with my pendrive, I need data which are on it, but...:

1. `lsusb` (after a few min it wouldn't see it again):

   Bus 002 Device 023: ID 0951:1642 Kingston Technology DT101 G2
2. `dmesg | grep sd` -> didnt see it, so I used only `dmesg`:

   ```
   [ 4293.962452] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
   [ 4293.963549] scsi11 : usb-storage 2-1:1.0
   [ 4315.984032] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
   [ 4331.096037] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
   [ 4346.312045] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
   [ 4346.528035] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
   [ 4361.640034] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
   [ 4376.856035] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
   [ 4377.072046] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
   [ 4387.480025] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 18, error -110
   [ 4387.592034] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
   [ 4398.000024] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 18, error -110
   [ 4398.000100] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 18
   [ 4398.000186] scsi 11:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
   [ 4398.112038] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
   [ 4413.224038] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
   [ 4428.440053] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
   [ 4428.656039] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 20 using ehci-pci
   [ 4443.768042] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
   [ 4458.984057] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
   [ 4459.200038] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 21 using ehci-pci
   [ 4469.608032] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 21, error -110
   [ 4469.720042] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 22 using ehci-pci
   [ 4480.128018] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 22, error -110
   [ 4480.128053] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
   [ 4480.392037] usb 6-1: new full-speed USB device number 10 using uhci_hcd
   [ 4495.708037] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
   [ 4510.924046] usb 6-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
   [ 4511.140028] usb 6-1: new full-speed USB device number 11 using uhci_hcd
   ```
3. `fdisk` also didnt see it
4. I clean pendrive with petrol - it works (Windows 8 has see it - but it has problems with drivers...)

Answer (score 0):

According to the `dmesg` excerpt, the disappearance of the device in the `lsusb` listing, and the driver issues Windows reports, your USB drive is terminally broken. A good data recovery tech may be able to salvage the data on it, since often only the USB interface chip is broken, not the flash memory or its controller.